# Mendeley is crashing on MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, mendeley

I have a problem starting Mendeley on MacBook Pro (10.13 (High Sierra)). It used to work before, but after the last update, i.e., 1.19.4.OSX.Universal, it pops up the following window every time I start it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgUlo.png)

I appreciate your help. In the meantime, I am contacting Mendeley.

Cheers,
/Nas

Comment: Not sure if you can expect any help on this site, as that clearly seems to be a bug on their side.

Comment: You are right: to fix the problem, "Please follow the steps below: 1. Go to the list of applications > Right Click on Mendeley > Get info 2. Tick the box ‘Open in low resolution’ > Save/Apply/Ok" - Mendeley support

Comment: Try also this: clear the Mendeley installation using the AppCleaner and do fresh installation. It works! I am not sure what cause the crash though!

Comment: You can answer your own question by pressing the button below. That way you could help others with the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I received an answer from the Mendeley support team:

> Please follow the steps below:
>
> 1. Go to the list of applications > Right Click on Mendeley > Get info
> 2. Tick the box ‘Open in low resolution’ > Save/Apply/Ok

An alternative that worked for me is clean installation, i.e., after removing the Medeley app using the AppCleaner (normal uninstallation does not solve the problem).

Comment: Low resolution looks very uncomfortable.

Answer (score 0):

To uninstall Mendeley without uninstallation apps such as AppCleaner, one can try deleting `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Mendeley Desktop` and `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Mendeley Ltd`. For me, deleting both folders even without reinstallation fixed the crash problem.